# Finding the electric field generated by a charge in cubic torus space(three-torus)

Tags: electrostatics

Imagine you are in a cubic torus space(three-torus) where if you go far enough in one direction you come back to where you started. Now imagine you have a charge in this space. Due to the geometry of the space, it would look like the charge was in a primitive cubic lattice. Unfortunately, if you try to calculate what the electric field from the charge is in this space, everything goes to infinity. This doesn't occur if there are multiple charges that make the net charge 0 though. Since the total field of the system is a superposition of the fields of every individual charge, I was wondering if there was a simple way to represent the field of a single charge in this system with no infinities breaking everything. I figure this could be useful for electrodynamics simulations. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It is not obvious that there is any proper answer. Some topologies rule out certain fields. For example, Visser shows in his book on Lorenzian wormholes that non-orientable spacetimes are incompatible with the weak force. I would not be surprised to see that nonzero net electric changes are forbidden on torus spacetimes (magnetic fields seem ok - divergence clearly plays a role).

Comment: I'm currently hoping that I can try to find the derivative of the electric field and hope that gives me some useful information.